# How do I display multiple cells inside one Ag-Grid cell?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

My problem is that I need to display several cells inside one cell, I have already studied all the ag-grid documentation and have not found anything that could help me. There are only guesses how it could be done, but I'm not sure that it will work. Here is an example in excel [how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSpWq.png)

I tried to do it using [Row Spanning](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-spanning/#row-spanning-example), but that's not it, it combines cells into one and gives access only to the one that you used rowspan. The documentation in the example shows that there they say one cell occupies a height of 2 cells and everything is fine there, but this is not quite true, [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLqb8.jpg).

Here's how I tried to do [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dArRb.png). But i need like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi9kV.jpg)...

Here's what I wrote [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zwVGIbrJKdOBabdE?preview)

```
function rowSpan(params: RowSpanParams) {
  return params.data.tasks.length > 0 ? params.data.tasks.length : 1;
}

public columnDefs: (ColDef | ColGroupDef)[] = [
    {
      headerName: 'Code',
      field: 'code',
      editable: true,
      onCellClicked(event) {
        window.location.href = `/shots/${event.data.id}`;
      },
      rowSpan: rowSpan,
      cellClass: "cell",
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Sequence',
      field: 'sequence.code',
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      headerName: 'ANIM',
      children: [
        {
          headerName: 'Status',
          field: 'tasks.status',
          columnGroupShow: 'closed',
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Task Name',
          field: 'tasks',
          columnGroupShow: 'closed',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

I will also clarify that I get an array of objects from the server.

```
[
 {
  "code": "sc01_0090",
  "description": null,
  "sequence": {
    "code": "sc01"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "content": "layout",
      "status": "wtg"
    },
    {
      "content": "animation",
      "status": "ip"
    },
    {
      "content": "lighting",
      "status": "wtg"
    },
    {
      "content": "compose",
      "status": "wtg"
    }
  ]
 },
 ...
]
```

Comment: If you could make a plunker or similar that could be fiddled with, you may find you get more interest in the question....
It's best to adjust a working example from the ag-grid website as a starting point

Comment: OK, got it. Here's plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/zwVGIbrJKdOBabdE?preview

Comment: In this example, I made an ANIM column in which it should look like this, but only inside one row are divided into several rows. Right now they're just like one line.. I hope you understand my thought..)

Comment: Ah I think I understand more.  Why do you not want to use RowSpanning?  It has the appearance and functionality of one cell despite just hiding the other cells underneath.  Is there another reason it doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Please check this and tell me your thoughts: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-spanning/#row-spanning-complex-example